# Plotting multiple values to one key in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib

I am trying to make a scatter plot with this dictionary

```
d = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15], 5: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]}
```

I want the keys to be in X-axis and the values to be on Y-axis, and also to show a legend with different key values. I have tried this code-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15], 5: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]}
colors = list("rgbk")
x, y =[], []
for i in d.keys():
   for j in d[i]:
       x.append(i)
       y.append(j)
   plt.scatter(x, y, color = colors.pop())
   plt.legend(d.keys())
plt.show()
```

But this is giving me a plot with points with only one colour but the legends are alright.

[image: This is the output image that I am getting]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use `plt.subplots()` in this case, so you can reuse the same `axis`. The colour iteration comes for free but I left it in, not sure if you prefer `rgbk`.

When possible, avoid for-loops in Python for better readability and performance.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15], 5: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]}
colors = list("rgbk")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for x, ys in d.items():
    ax.scatter([x] * len(ys), ys, color = colors.pop(), label=x)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

If you are dealing with large arrays, consider using `numpy`. In this case you can rescale the `key` for example like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15], 5: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]}
colors = list("rgbk")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for x, ys in d.items():
    ax.scatter(np.full_like(ys, x), ys, color = colors.pop(), label=x)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You initialize the `x` and `y` lists before the loop. In each iteration, you add new values to the list, and they overpaint the old points. Move the line `x, y =[], []` into the loop.

Comment: Also put `plt.legend(d.keys())` outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15], 5: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]}

for i in d.keys():
   for j in d[i]:
       plt.scatter(i,j,color=(i/10,i/10,i/10))
   plt.legend(d.keys())
plt.show()
```